# Can I use the music from Clips in iMovie?

Tags: imovie, clips.app

Does anyone know if there is a way to use the music from the Clips app on iOS in iMovie on macOS?

For example, there is a song "Aether" by Darren King.

I'd like a raw MP3/AIFF/whatever of this entire song so I can use it in iMovie without having to record a giant clip which will also include mic input.

Comment: Check out this link: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH14710?locale=en_US In summary, choose the clip with audio, then click on *Modify*, then *Detach Audio* (or OPTION+COMMAD+B). Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @ProGrammer, I wasn't clear in my question, I'll update it.

Comment: Actually it seems you can mute the source video so this is an option. I'll do that for now, thanks @ProGrammer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I see possible is the following:

1. Choose the music you want in Clips.
2. Record a clip that’s at least as long as the music you want (you could always hold then swipe up on the record button and come back 5 minutes later if you’re not sure how long the music clip is).
3. Select the clip you just recorded and tap “Mute.”
4. Tap the Share button and tap “Copy to iMovie.” (Yes, we’ll eventually get it to iMovie on macOS).
5. In iMovie for iOS, trim the clip to the desired length.
6. Tap “Done” then tap the share button, then tap “Save Video.”
7. Once the video has exported, go to Photos on your iOS device and select the clip you just exported. Tap the share button, then air drop it to your Mac. You could also use the photos app on your Mac to import the clip if you wish.
8. On your Mac, open iMovie and drag in the clip.
9. Click, then Two-finger-click the clip, then click, “Detach Audio.”
10. Drag the audio to be attached to a different clip.
11. Click, then Two-finger-click the video clip, then hit “delete” on your keyboard. Now you can drag the audio wherever you want to use it in your Project.

Let me know if any of that doesn’t make sense. I tested it using iPad mini 4 on iOS 11 and MacBook Pro with high sierra before posting so I know it works.